# I cannot find interpolate key of grease pencil in tab

Tags: animation, shortcut, grease-pencil, interpolation

I want to interpolate keyframes in grease pencil, but the interpolate key isn't found. In addition, although I tried to push shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>), it doesn't work.

Could you help me if you have any idea?

[image: Here is tab without interpolate key]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also, Make sure you are using the latest "Blender Builder" /
here is the link https://builder.blender.org/download/

I'm guessing you saw the youtube tutorial from OpenToonzTraining. you're using blender 2.78. If possible when you see his video you will see he is using 2.78.1

Me personally, I think I'll wait for blender 2.79, as there is a risk of instability with the builds as it says on top of it, but I don't know about that stuff yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips to follow for the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut to work:

- Make sure you're in *Edit Mode*
- Select the keyframes you want to interpolate
- Select the layer that you want to interpolate (make sure it shows as orange)
- Click on the timeline so the cursor lies between the two keyframes for interpolation
- Make sure your mouse is hovering over the *2D Viewport* (not the *Timeline*)